# How to update a specific property value of all elements in array using Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Let's say I already have an Array of `ViewHolder` which is `viewHolderList: [ViewHolder]`.
I want all `isMarried` field of elements to "**false**" in a single line without looping.

```
struct ViewHolder {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
    var isMarried: Bool = true
}
```

Comment: How would you expect to chance all elements without iterating them all? Btw you should declare all properties as non optional and constants. Only declare a property as optional if they might be nil.

Comment: @LeoDabus , there are native methods like "filter" and "map" for Array that I can't use properly at the moment.

Comment: have you tried `Map` function ?

Comment: they will loop as well

Comment: No idea how to use map. It's saying '$0.' is immutable.

Comment: you can use computed property to make is work without loop. and hold you true/false flag in global variable.
but this is not good practice, just a patch.

Comment: I'm doing something like this.. but it seems not working viewHolderList.map { $0.isMarried == false }

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just need to iterate your array `indices` using `forEach` method and use the array index to update its element property:

```
struct ViewHolder {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    var isMarried: Bool
}

var viewHolders: [ViewHolder] = [.init(name: "Steve Jobs", age: 56, isMarried: true),
                                 .init(name: "Tim Cook", age: 59, isMarried: true)]


viewHolders.indices.forEach {
    viewHolders[$0].isMarried = false
}

viewHolders  // [{name "Steve Jobs", age 56, isMarried false}, {name "Tim Cook", age 59, isMarried false}]
```

---

You can also extend MutableCollection and create a mutating method to map a specific property of your collection elements as follow:

```
extension MutableCollection {
    mutating func mapProperty<T>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Element, T>, _ value: T) {
        indices.forEach { self[$0][keyPath: keyPath] = value }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
viewHolders.mapProperty(\.isMarried, false)
viewHolders  // [{name "Steve Jobs", age 56, isMarried false}, {name "Tim Cook", age 59, isMarried false}]
```